# extract Min function is not working properly

Tags: c++, fibonacci-heap

I got an assignment but I'm stuck in the titled problem. It will be very glad that you will help me to solve this. The quick over review I have provided the classes and main file for which I have to implemented the function and run the code. There are two files named fheap.hpp and djstra.hpp and the main file.

```
int main(){

    // Fibonacci Heap

    FibonacciHeap<int> heap(3);
    std::cout<<(heap.get_min()==std::nullopt)<<std::endl;

    std::vector<int> inserted;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i) {
        int temp = rand() % 100+1;
        heap.insert(temp);
        cout << temp;
        cout << "inserted  & min :";
        cout << heap.get_min().value() << endl;

    }

    std::cout<<heap.get_min().value()<<std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; ++j) {
        int min_value = heap.extract_min().value();
        cout << "min_value: ";
        std::cout << min_value;
        cout << "  size: ";
        cout << heap.size()<<endl;
    }


    // Dijkstra's Algorithm

    edges_t edges1 = {{0, 1, 3.0f},
                      {0, 2, 1.0f},
                      {1, 2, 7.0f},
                      {1, 3, 5.0f},
                      {1, 4, 1.0f},
                      {2, 3, 2.0f},
                      {3, 4, 7.0f}};


    Graph g1(5, edges1, GraphType::UNDIRECTED);

    std::unordered_map<vertex_t, std::optional<std::tuple<vertex_t, edge_weight_t>>> result
            = dijkstra_shortest_path(g1, 2);

    // Previous vertex of src are not checked.
    std::vector<vertex_t> previous = {2, 0, (vertex_t)-1, 2, 1};
    std::vector<edge_weight_t> dist = {1.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 5.0f};


    // The printed result should be same as above.

    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 5 && i!=2 ; ++i) {
        std::cout<<"[vertex i] ";
        std::cout<<"previous: "<<std::get<0>(result[i].value())<<", ";
        std::cout<<"distance: "<<std::get<1>(result[i].value())<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Suprisingly the djstra part is giving me the required output. second file loop in the main section throws memory error **Edit:** ( meaning it exits the program with some memory address and sometimes show `what() std:: optional error`). The fheap class is below that are responsible for it are below:

```
#ifndef __FHEAP_H_
#define __FHEAP_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
class PriorityQueue {
public:
    virtual void insert(const T& item) = 0;
    virtual std::optional<T> extract_min() = 0;
    virtual bool is_empty() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class FibonacciNode {
public:
    // Constructors
    FibonacciNode()
            :key(), degree(0), marked(false), child(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

    FibonacciNode(const T& item)
            :key(item), degree(0), marked(false), child(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

    // Destructor
    ~FibonacciNode() = default;

    T key;
    size_t degree;
    bool marked;

    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> right;
    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> child;
    // NOTE: To prevent circular reference, left/parent pointer should be set to weak_ptr.
    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> left;
    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> parent;
};

template <typename T>
class FibonacciHeap : public PriorityQueue<T> {
public:
    // Constructors
    FibonacciHeap()
            : min_node(nullptr), size_(0) {}
    FibonacciHeap(const T& item)
            : min_node(nullptr), size_(0) { insert(item); }

    // Disable copy constructor.
    FibonacciHeap(const FibonacciHeap<T> &);

    // Destructor
    //~FibonacciHeap();

    void insert(const T& item) override;
    void insert(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& node);

    // Return raw pointer of the min_node.
    FibonacciNode<T>* get_min_node() { return min_node.get(); }

    std::optional<T> get_min() const;

    std::optional<T> extract_min() override;
    std::optional<T> extract_min1();
    void decrease_key(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& x, T new_key);

    void remove(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& node);

    bool is_empty() const override { return !size_; }

    size_t size() const { return size_; }

private:

    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> min_node;
    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> min;
    size_t size_;

    void consolidate();
    void merge(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& x, std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& y);
    void cut(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& x);
    void recursive_cut(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& x);

};

template <typename T>
void FibonacciHeap<T>::insert(const T& item) {
    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> node = std::make_shared<FibonacciNode<T>>(item);
    insert(node);
}
template <typename T>
std::optional<T> FibonacciHeap<T>::get_min() const {
    if (min_node) {
        return min_node->key;
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void FibonacciHeap<T>::insert(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& node) {
// Make the new node the right sibling of the min_node, if it exists
    if (min_node) {
        node->right = min_node->right;
        min_node->right = node;
        node->left = min_node;
        node->right->left = node;
    }
// Otherwise, make the new node the min_node and its own right sibling
    else {
        min_node = node;
        node->right = node;
        node->left = node;
    }
// If the new node has a smaller key than the current min_node, update min_node
    if (node->key < min_node->key) {
        min_node = node;
    }
// Increase the size of the heap
    ++size_;
}



template <typename T>
std::optional<T> FibonacciHeap<T>::extract_min() {
    // Return nullopt if the heap is empty
    if (!min_node) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    // Store the min_node in a temporary variable
    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> z = min_node;

    // If the min_node has children, add them to the root list
    if (z->child) {
        std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> child = z->child;
        do {
            child->parent.reset();
            child = child->right;
        } while (child != z->child);
        merge(min_node, z->child);
    }

    // Remove the min_node from the root list
    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> left = z->left;
    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> right = z->right;
    left->right = right;
    right->left = left;

    // If the min_node was the only node in the heap, set min_node to nullptr
    if (z == right) {
        min_node.reset();
    }
        // Otherwise, set the new min_node to be the node that was previously to the right of z
    else {
        min_node = right;
        consolidate();
    }

    // Decrease the size of the heap
    --size_;

    // Return the key of the extracted min_node
    return z->key;
}

template <typename T>
void FibonacciHeap<T>::decrease_key(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& x, T new_key) {
// If the new key is greater than the current key, throw an exception
    if (new_key > x->key) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("New key is greater than current key.");
    }
// Update the key of the node
    x->key = new_key;
// If the node has a parent and its new key is smaller than its parent's key, cut it from its parent and add it to the root list
    auto parent = x->parent.lock();
    if (parent && x->key < parent->key) {
        cut(x);
    }
// If the node's new key is smaller than the current min_node's key, update min_node
    if (x->key < min_node->key) {
        min_node = x;
    }
}



template <typename T>
void FibonacciHeap<T>::remove(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& x) {
    // Set the key of the node to be removed to the minimum value
    x->key = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    // Perform a decrease key operation on the node to be removed
    decrease_key(x, std::numeric_limits<T>::min());
    // Extract the minimum value, which should be the node to be removed
    extract_min();
}

template <typename T>
void FibonacciHeap<T>::consolidate() {
    float phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0;
    int len = int(log(size_) / log(phi)) + 10;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>> A(len, nullptr);

    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> w = min_node;
    std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> x = w;
    do {
        x = x->right;
        std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> y = x;
        int d = y->degree;
        while (A[d]) {
            std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> z = A[d];
            if (y->key > z->key) {
                std::swap(y, z);
            }
            merge(y, z);
            A[d] = nullptr;
            ++d;
        }
        A[d] = y;
    } while (w != x);

    min_node.reset();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (A[i]) {
            if (min_node) {
                A[i]->right = min_node->right;
                min_node->right = A[i];
                A[i]->left = min_node;
                A[i]->right->left = A[i];
                if (A[i]->key < min_node->key) {
                    min_node = A[i];
                }
            }
            else {
                min_node = A[i];
                min_node->right = min_node;
                min_node->left = min_node;
            }
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void FibonacciHeap<T>::merge(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& x, std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& y) {
// Make x the right sibling of y
    x->right = y->right;
    y->right->left = x;
    y->right = x;
    x->left = y;
// If x has a smaller key than y, make x the new min_node
    if (x->key < y->key) {
        min_node = x;
    }
// Otherwise, make y the new min_node
    else {
        min_node = y;
    }
// Increase the size of the heap
    size_ += 2;
}

template <typename T>
void FibonacciHeap<T>::cut(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& x) {
// Get a pointer to the parent of x
    auto parent = x->parent;
// If x has no parent, we do not need to cut it
    if (!parent) return;

// Remove x from the child list of parent
    if (x->right == x) {
        parent->child = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        x->right->left = x->left;
        x->left->right = x->right;
        if (parent->child == x) {
            parent->child = x->right;
        }
    }

// Decrease the degree of parent
    --parent->degree;

// Add x to the root list of the heap
    x->right = min_node->right;
    min_node->right = x;
    x->left = min_node;
    x->right->left = x;

// Clear the parent and marked fields of x
    x->parent.reset();
    x->marked = false;
}

template <typename T>
void FibonacciHeap<T>::recursive_cut(std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>>& x) {
    // Get the parent of the node
    auto parent = x->parent.lock();

    // If the node has a parent, cut it from the parent and perform a recursive cut on the parent
    if (parent) {
        if (x->marked) {
            // Cut the node from the parent
            cut(x);
            // Perform a recursive cut on the parent
            recursive_cut(parent);
        }
            // If the node is not marked, mark it
        else {
            x->marked = true;
        }
    }
}
#endif // __FHEAP_H_
```

I know, I'm asking a very long question. I've tried every approach but it's not solving.

I Tried debugging the code and introducing cout operations where I think is error after debugging is in the line
`

```
std::shared_ptr<FibonacciNode<T>> z = A[d];
```

I tried ArrayList but still no change.

Edit: Second for loop means the 2nd loop in int main ()

Comment: OT: All symbols beginning with double underscore, or a single underscore and an upper-case letter, are *reserved*. You should not define such symbols anywhere in your code, not as variable, not as macros, not as functions or anything else. For more information see e.g. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: To help with debugging, not only write out details (including variable values) also use an actual [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line. Often it can also help if you use pen and paper to write down observations, and compare those with the design and possible flow-graphs you've written.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I usually don't use underscores but the classes that I've provided without function definition had already had underscores in them. So, I'm not left with the choice just to use them.

Comment: Gotcha I'll try that, I'm using Clion built-in debugger

Comment: You mean that a skeleton header file, with the header guard `#ifndef __FHEAP_H_` etc., was provided to you by your teacher (or someone else)? Then you should send them that link about the underscore rules.

Comment: yeah, it's been provide by my teacher. I'm spending two days on this problem. gonna try the debugging approach

Comment: Please explain what the "second file loop" is, and be more specific than "throws memory error".

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for the suggestions. I've added tham in the question. Also second loop means the 2nd loop in int main. And by memory error I means it exits the program with a memory address `program exits with code 0xAAB4C` something like this.

Comment: That's not an address but an error code in hexadecimal notation, and you can probably find out what it means through a web search. (Also, you should verify that your `optional`s contain values before accessing them instead of assuming that they do just because they would if there weren't any bugs.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks man, It really helped me and I found out the consolidate() function is causing the error after not altering the heap.